Is it safe to throw exception in WTelegramClient OnOther?
I use this fantastic .Net package WTelegramClient, but I would really prefer handling fatal reactor errors through catching an exception outside client methods, naturally disposing the client and then attempting to reconnect with new client instance.
Question: is it safe to throw an exception in OnOther for ReactorError, expecting it to bubble up through the client?

Define "being safe". And: why not just give it a try (i.e. create a "Proof Of Concept")?

By "being safe" I mean that it won't be suppressed internally under some conditions.
Rather than PoC'ing and hoping it'll work for all the cases I'm asking those who know.

Well, meanwhile you could PoC one case. If that fails you already know it's not safe by your definition. That may actually save you some time waiting for an answer.

If it passes it may not work for all the cases. Even if it fails, such behavior may be considered for the next release, it's not unheard of. Somebody out there knows definitive answer, and I really don't see any good reason not to ask.

I didn't say "don't ask" - I asked you why you don't PoC. Now I know. All is good. I even counter-voted the DV. I hope someone can tell you. About future changes: that's a common problem anywhere. If it is not explicitly states in some "RoadMap" or similar, you (or anybody) just cannot know for sure. That's a risk we all are taking on a daily basis.

I really hope that developer answers here - he is extremely responsive to very rare open issues. This question is not really an issue, and the answer can benefit others as well so I posted it here. I should have explained that in the first place. Long day.

You can always add to / improve the question. It's even encouraged - as long as it doesn't change the question fundamentally.

Taking a quick look at the code for the Client class on github, the only call to invoke OnOther is wrapped in a try-catch which handles and logs the exception.
The developer seems to suggest that you should deal with fatal errors by calling dispose within your OnOther handler method - see this issue.

You are correct, it is indeed being suppressed. Somehow I missed it even though I stared straight at it. Perhaps it's time to call it and get some sleep :) Thank you for looking into it.

see also https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_ReactorError.cs

I"ve seen that, and ended up following that example. Though I consider WTelegramClient a library, not a framework, and as such my code was expecting to catch any errors in form of exceptions thrown by Client class. That is until I learned the special case of reactor failure. If such failure is not handled by recreating and reconnecting the client, the following call to Messages_GetHistory just hangs dead.
No biggie after all, it's just hot swapping client inside client event feels a bit odd.
By the way, you may want to add unsubscribing event handlers to your example.
